# Quotient rule for limits of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Suppose that, $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)$ exist and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)\neq0$. Then, prove that $$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)}{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)}$$

Comment: I guess you should consult a textbook. A proof has to be provided in a textbook on real analysis. The key is to prove the $\epsilon-\delta$ relation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This kind of questions are discouraged on this site. This is part of the basic theory of Calculus and can be found in any decent Calculus textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ and $L$ be the limits of $f$ and $g$ respectively. Let $\epsilon > 0 $ and choose $\delta > 0 $ such that for $|x-x_0| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - K| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x) - L| < \epsilon.$ We can also conveniently suppose that in this range $|g(x)| \geq  |L|/2 .$ Then

\begin{align} |f(x)/g(x) - K/L| &= \bigg|\frac{f(x)L - Kg(x)}{Lg(x)}\bigg| \\
&= \bigg|\frac{f(x)L - KL + KL - Kg(x)}{Lg(x)}\bigg| \\
&= \bigg|\frac{L(f(x) - K) + K(L - g(x))}{Lg(x)}\bigg| \\
&< \epsilon(L+K)/L|g(x)|\\
&\leq \epsilon2(L+K)/L^2.
\end{align}
Of course if you want all of this to be neatly less than $\epsilon$ then you could change your values of $\delta$ accordingly.